# An inequality for absolute total curvature in Riemannian surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let be $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ a compact (Riemannian) surface and let be $K$ the gaussian curvature of $M$.

I want to prove that
$$ \int_{M} |K| \geq 4\pi(1+g(M))$$ 
where $g(M)$ is the genus of $M$. I tried using the following inequalities:

$$  \int _M |K|=\int_{K>0} K - \int_{K<0} K \geq 4\pi -\int_{K<0} K\geq 4\pi -\int_M K$$

but I had no luck even using Gauss Bonnet. Any hint?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What is $K$? Please include your definition of $K$ in the question.

Comment: I explained, thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you just throw away too much:

$$\begin{split}
\int_M |K| &= \int_{K>0} K - \int_{K<0} K = \int_{K>0} K - \left(\int_{K<0} K + \int_{K>0} K - \int_{K>0} K\right)\\
&= \int_{K>0} K - \left(\int_M K - \int_{K>0}K \right)\\
&= 2\int_{K>0} K - \int_M K\ .
\end{split}$$

Comment: @John, I don't see what is happening in your last equality. Can you explain how you end up with that?

Comment: I added one more line, is it okay now? @Hrodelbert

Comment: @John, That was embarrassingly easy: for some reason I had not spotted the crucial minus sign. Thanks anyway!