# What global property gives the total smoothness of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

For example, every torus has zero total curvature.

Given two tori with the same surface area, what quantity gives the total smoothness of the torus. i.e. it would be low for one with mostly low curvature everywhere and high for one which is bumpy or had high surface area like a really thin torus.

Could you combine these quantities to show that a nice ordinary smooth torus, not too thin and not too thick would be a maximum for this combination?

Comment: Probably take the absolute value of curvature instead. Maybe look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_absolute_curvature

Comment: Why would you take the absolute value and not for example the square or fourth power. Is there any theorems behind this?

Comment: In fact the absolute value's not going to be much use: for any torus, $ \int_T |K| \, dS = 8\pi$.

Comment: Is that just for ordinary tori. Because for general tori you could just add a spike or bump to it to add more absolute curvature.

Comment: @Chappers I am not sure this is true. For one thing you can take the standard torus R^2 / Z^2 which has constant Gaussian curvature 0

Comment: It might be useful to point out that, unless I'm mistaken, we're talking about Tori as a topological equivalence class. If we were to use the definition from Euclidean Geometry, the question would be rather trivial.

Comment: @Chappers: I believe that's not true. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914018/prove-that-int-k-geq-8-pi-for-a-compact-surface-with-genus-0/1916256#1916256) and my answer.

Comment: @user399601: I believed we were restricting to surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$. At any rate, my vote is for total absolute curvature. If your surface is embedded in $\Bbb R^4$, you need to learn about Lipschitz-Killing curvature (also in the paper I referenced in the link above).

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah, you're right, I wasn't specific enough. For the standard embedding $((a+b\sin{v})\cos{u},(a+b\sin{v})\sin{u},b\cos{u})$, the result does hold ($\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{|\sin{v}|}{a+b\sin{v}} (a+b\sin{v}) \, dv \, du = 8\pi $). And since it doesn't distinguish clearly different-shaped tori in this embedding, it doesn't look like a good measure, at least to me.

Comment: It does distinguish them, @Chappers. When you distort the shape and add bumps, you'll add total curvature. That follows from the theorem in my answer I linked (and the proof is in the paper I linked there).